# Timed out waiting for debugee to spawn - Python debugger in VSCode - Fedora 33 - Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm using the `Docker` and the `Python` extensions in VSCode, I'm developing remotely on my container using VSCode attach to container option.

When I'm trying to debug my Python module the editor loading for a few seconds and then crashes.

[image]

I looked online for solutions and did not find anything that works.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the content of "launch.json"? In order to prevent the computer from running other applications that take up a lot of memory at the same time to cause the computer to freeze, and the vscode debugging time is too long, please try to close other unnecessary processes and reload VSCode.

Comment: I have the same error. It worked for me when I started VS Code via my start menu, and not when started using `code .` in the WSL remote Ubuntu-20.04 shell. But I'm unsure whether that is the cause for this. It sometimes workes and sometimes not when I started it with `code .`.